# Combining two view into one result set with transform?

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I have a couple of views that generates the following two outputs in SQL Server.
First one (Flats output) shows the number of flats in a particular town with Tileroofs and Brickwalls.  Second one shows the same, but for houses.

What I'm trying to do is to create a final table that looks like the 3rd example where the flats and house counts are combined with the corresponding Tileroof and Brickwall combinations.

I have tried union and then grouping, but I'm really struggling to get the Flats and Houses count columns side by side.  Is anyone able to help please?

Thanks

```
--View one
| Town | Flats | TileRoofs | Brick Wall |
-----------------------------------------
| A    | 3     | Y         | N          |
| A    | 4     | N         | Y          |
| A    | 8     | N         | N          |


--View two
| Town | Houses | TileRoofs | Brick Wall |
------------------------------------------
| A    | 1      | Y         | Y          |
| A    | 2      | Y         | N          |
| A    | 5      | N         | Y          |
| A    | 2      | N         | N          |


--Prefered output, by combining the two--

| Town | Flats | Houses | TileRoofs | Brick Wall |
--------------------------------------------------
| A    | 0     |  1     | Y         | Y          |
| A    | 3     |  2     | Y         | N          |
| A    | 4     |  5     | N         | Y          |
| A    | 8     |  2     | N         | N          |
```

Comment: Use Full Outer join on identical columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Full outer join might help here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

```
select isnull(a.Town, b.Town) Town,
       isnull(a.TileRoofs, b.TileRoofs) TileRoofs,
       isnull(a.[Brick wall], b.[Brick wall]) [Brick wall],
       isnull(a.Flats, 0) Flats,
       isnull(b.Houses, 0) Houses
  from ViewOne a
  full outer join ViewTwo b
    on a.Town = b.Town
   and a.TileRoofs = b.TileRoofs
   and a.[Brick wall] = b.[Brick wall]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    v2.Town ,coalesce(v1.flat,0) as flat,v2.houses,v2.TileRoofs, v2.Brick, v2.Wall 
from
    view2 as v2 left join view1 as v1
on v1.town=v2.town
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be after a full outer join

```
select 
    houses.town,
    flats.flats, 
    houses.houses,
    houses.BrickWall,
    houses.TileRoofs
from flats
full outer join houses
    on houses.town=flats.town
    and houses.TileRoofs = flats.TileRoofs
    and houses.BrickWall = flats.BrickWall
```